# Python - Altering a list that is being iterated. Out of Scope

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, iterator

x2012 is a list of dates in the form `['01/01/2013','02/01/2013',...]`.

I'm trying to iterate through x2012 and change the values from (string) dates to floats.

`print(row)` -prints floats.

`for row in x:print(row)` -prints (string) dates.

`for row in x2012:print(row)` -prints (string) dates.

```
def xToFloat(x):
    for row in x:
        day,month,year=row.split('/')
        row=date(int(year),int(month),int(day)).toordinal()
        print(row)
    for row in x:print(row)

xToFloat(x2012)

for row in x2012:
    print(row)
```

Why this loss of scope when exiting an iteration of for loop?

Comment: try to fix indentation first

Comment: edited to correct indentation.  This is the code which represents the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not changing the values in the list. You are assigning the result of `.toordinal()` to a local variable `row` only, rebinding that variable.

To change elements *in the list* you need to assign back to the list indices:

```
def xToFloat(x):
    for i, row in enumerate(x):
        day, month, year = row.split('/')
        row = date(int(year), int(month), int(day)).toordinal()
        x[i] = row
```

Alternatively, generate a new list with a list comprehension; I'm using `datetime.strptime()` here to parse the input instead of using string splitting and `int()`:

```
[datetime.strptime(dt, '%d/%m/%Y').toordinal() for dt in x]
```

You can replace all elements of `x` with the output with:

```
x[:] = [datetime.strptime(dt, '%d/%m/%Y').toordinal() for dt in x]
```